# How to set window position to locate it to the top of the screen on MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I'm trying to set position of new dialog in MFC, what i do:

```
SetWindowPos(&this->wndTopMost, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOSIZE);
```

in the InitDialog() of this window, but after execution, this window appears on center of my screen... What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing anything wrong, I've used this as

Can you please try this with minor modification

```
::SetWindowPos(this->wndTopMost->GetSafeHwnd(), HWND_TOPMOST, 0,0,0,0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

or

```
this->wndTopMost.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
```

Comment: Noone works for me... May be the reason is that this is modeless dialog and it has global declaration in my code, such as: LoadDlg *dlg = new LoadDlg();

Comment: Yes may be in my case it was modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question:** How to set window position to locate it to the top of the screen on MFC?

If you don't want to move the location of the window nor do you want to resize it;

```
SetWindowPos(&CWnd::wndTopMost, 0 , 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
```

If you call it inside a window/dialog, no `::` prefix is needed since we can use [MFC's version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1yzfz6d.aspx) of the function

Answer (score 0):

Found solution!

When i set x = 0 and y = 0 in my case (Win7) window always appears in the center of the screen. Like if decart system...
But when i changed it.. to (1200, 0) it appears in the top right corner, just like i need to... do not know how it connected, but thanks all of you, who helped me.